# Retrieve anonymous type from the web in C#

Tags: c#, xml, json

I'm trying to retrieve some data from the web. The data is served either as JSON object or XML: in both cases I'd like **not to build a model** based on the structure of this XML/JSON but to just retrieve the data I need.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
"http://www.someAPI.com/api.xml",
requestContent);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

HttpContent content = response.Content;
```

If I have to build a model based on the data structure I'll receive back I'll do it: I just want to know if there is any alternative. Can I parse `content` as an anonymous type and, say, retrieve the data as arbitrary fields or properties or array indexes?

Let's say: `response.Countries[5].CountryId`. Is it possible in any of these 2 types (JSON and XML)? How can I do it?

Comment: You should reformulate your questions: as it is now, the answers are **Yes** and **Yes**.  But I guess that does not help you all that much.

Comment: You could try assigning the content you get back to a [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) variable and accessing the properties/values off that - but then you'd need to know beforehand what the names of the properties are

Comment: off course, I already know the data structure. I just don't want to build a model over it.

Comment: Have you looked at using the `XPath` selectors in .NET?  These along with `LINQ` and the `XDocument` class provide a really easy and powerful way to access XML data.

Comment: A model as in, having to create a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) just to be able to access the content? Then `dynamic` might be a neat way to get around that.

Comment: @Saturnix I agree with Sameer Singh, I would think the dynamic variable would be the best route to go? (i.e. putting the `response.Content` into a dynamic var would do the trick, then you could call the known property directly.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**EDIT #2:**

I've added a note below about using the excellent [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library to deserialize to a `dynamic` object.

---

**EDIT #1:**

Thanks to [Hoghweed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995546/501556), my answer below is now more complete. Specifically, we need to *cast* the `HttpContent` we get from `HttpResponseMessage.Content` to [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) in order for the `dynamic`-ness to work as expected:

```cs
dynamic content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result;
var myPropertyValue = content.MyProperty;
```

To get the [`ReadAsync<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541) extension method though, you'd need to use [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) to download and install `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` from the [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) package ([here's the "old" Nuget page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting), which mentions that it is now included in the above package).

---

**Original Answer:**

So, you don't want to have to create a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) and have to manage its properties as the XML/JSON structure you get back changes. [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) seems perfect for your use case:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
"http://www.someAPI.com/api.xml", requestContent);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

dynamic content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result; // Notice the use of the dynamic keyword
var myPropertyValue = content.MyProperty; // Compiles just fine, retrieves the value of this at runtime (as long as it exists, of course)
```

**Specifically regarding XML:** you could try [Anoop Madhusudanan's `ElasticObject`](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/02/introducing-elasticobject-for-net-40.html) which might be very helpful when converting between `dynamic` and `XML`, and back.

**Specifically regarding JSON:** you could use  [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) do something like this:

```cs
dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
var myPropertyValue = content.MyProperty;
```

The up-side is that you won't take a dependency on the [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) package (which, as of `v4.0.30506.0`, depends on Json.NET). The downside is that you won't be able to use this for XML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The [`ExpandoObject`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx?Redirected=true) seems to be .NET 4.0's official answer to things like the `ElasticObject`.

Comment: Yup - but `ElasticObject` is being actively developed on whereas `ExpandoObject` updates are tied to new releases of the .NET framework (though, that [looks to be changing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151288.aspx)). It also depends on whether the OP would be allowed to use third-party software or not.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I'm having some big issues with my code not compiling right now but I'll test the solution you posted as soon as I can and mark your answer.

Comment: @SameerSingh Indeed - after first-hand experience of how tricky it can be to get approval for third-party libraries, I try to find solutions that use the official stuff wherever possible. I hadn't seen `ElasticObject` before though... it looks great; I might have to try it.

Comment: it is not working at all.  'System.Net.Http.StreamContent' does not contain a definition for 'MyProperty'

Comment: Did you change `HttpContent content = response.Content;` to `dynamic content = response.Content;`?

Comment: @Saturnix please see my edit, and please let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the `HttpResponseMessage.Content` as a **dynamic** it's possible but not *accessing* it directly as dynamic, but using the proper extension method to read it's content as **ExpandoObject**.

I wrote a behavior test for that, it's clear is a test, but the context is similar to what your question is:

1. a **response object** with a json content (I used json in my test)
2. a dynamic resolution without a model object

The test is structured as:

1. Given an anonymous object
2. When creating an `HttpResponseMessage` with a content of this object using a JsonMedia Formatter
3. Then it's possible to access it as dynamic using an `ExpandoObject`

The test prerequisite is to install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
So, this is the code of the test

```
public class RetrieveAnonymousTypeFromTheWebInCSharp 
    : BehaviorTest
{
    private object _testModel;
    private HttpResponseMessage _message;

    protected override void Given()
    {
        _testModel = new
            {
                Id = 14,
                MyProperty = "Test property value"
            };
    }

    protected override void When()
    {
        _message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                       {
                           Content =
                               new ObjectContent(_testModel.GetType(),
                                                 _testModel,
                                                 new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
                                                     ())
                       };
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then()
    {
        //then properties could be retrieved back by dynamics
        dynamic content = _message.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result;
        var propertyvalue = content.MyProperty;
        Assert.That(propertyvalue, Is.Not.Null.And.EqualTo("Test property value"));
    }
}
```

This could be done sure for xml too.

Comment: Interesting - so all that's needed is the `.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result` to retrieve the `HttpContent` as `dynamic`?

Comment: Yes, I used it and waited for result in place reading the Result which blocks the Thread until the result is done, but you can use too continuation. But the important thing is that doing so, reading it as ExpandoObject you can then read it as dynamic doing what was your intention